# What is the difference between mongooseim.cfg at 2 different places

Tags: mongoose-im

I am using Mongooseim 3.2.0 and after compiling it from the source code, I can see the mongooseim.cfg at:

```
1. /MongooseIM/_build/prod/rel/mongooseim/etc/mongooseim.cfg
```

I can also see that in the [docs here](https://mongooseim.readthedocs.io/en/latest/authentication-backends/HTTP-authentication-module/) that there is another mongooseim.cfg at root level -

```
2. /MoongoosIM/rel/files/mongooseim.cfg
```

What is the difference between the two? My guess is path [1](https://mongooseim.readthedocs.io/en/latest/authentication-backends/HTTP-authentication-module/) file is copied to the path[2] after compiling the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Path 1 (`/MongooseIM/_build/prod/rel/mongooseim/etc/mongooseim.cfg`) is the actual config file of MongooseIM once it's built. You can tell that by `MongooseIM/_build` in the path - the `_build` directory doesn't exist in a fresh clone of the repository. To give you more context, `/MongooseIM/_build/prod/rel/mongooseim` is [a self-contained Erlang release of MongooseIM](http://erlang.org/doc/design_principles/release_structure.html). Change this file if you want to modify the config of this particular MongooseIM build - the changes will be lost after you rebuild.

Path 2 (`/MoongoosIM/rel/files/mongooseim.cfg`) is cloned as part of the repository - it's a config template. The specific values are defined in `rel/*vars.config` files and are substituted for the variables in the template file at build time depending on the Rebar3 profile in use (see `rebar.config` for profiles). Change this file if you want your changes to remain after consecutive rebuilds of the project.

To cut the long story short, when you run `make rel` the files `/MoongoosIM/rel/files/mongooseim.cfg` and `/MoongoosIM/rel/vars.config` are used to create `/MongooseIM/_build/prod/rel/mongooseim/etc/mongooseim.cfg`.

Comment: That's interesting. Thanks